# How to adjust damping for design of closed loop controller

Tags: matlab, control-theory, discrete-optimization

I have an 18 state state space model that I would like to discretize. To derive the sampling time, I decided to use the natural frequency and damping ratio from pole placement. The natural frequencies that I got were OK but the dampings are too low. Two out of the 18 damping ratios were actually negative. Does anyone know how I can increase the damping ratios that were negative to positive numbers? How do I select the poles of the closed loop system? The code that I wrote in Matlab is written below.
Thanks.

```
A_c= "System matrix"
B_c= "Input matrix"

%% Continuous-Time Control Design
lambda_tilde_c = eig(A_c)
K_c = place(A_c,B_c,lambda_tilde_c);
K_c = -K_c;

%% Analysis of the Continous-Time Closed-Loop System
lambda = eig(A_c+B_c*K_c);              % eigenvalues
[omega_0, zeta] = damp(A_c+B_c*K_c);    % natural frequencies (in rad/s) and damping
f = omega_0/(2*pi);                     % natural frequencies (in Hz)

%% Selection of the Sampling Period
T_r = omega_0(1)^(-1)*exp(acos(zeta(1))/tan(acos(zeta(1)))); % 
h = T_r/10
```

Comment: Are you sure that your chose a right forum?

Comment: You are setting the poles of the closed loop system to the poles of the open loop system... This doesn't seem to be useful, are you sure this is what you are trying to achieve? Because you can do the same with $K = 0$ (i.e. use no controller at all).

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg This is a question about control and Matlab, so the forum/tags are correct.

Comment: @SampleTime No it is not OK. How do I choose a good "lambda_tilde_c"?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Negative damping indicates your system is unstable, so to begin with, you should choose all poles to have negative real part. But it is also unclear to me how you are trying to derive the sampling period? Where is that formula from? Usually you have a certain samping period given (because of limitations of the digital controller)...

Comment: @SampleTime. I was going to choose the highest natural frequency and substitute that and its damping into "T_r = omega_0(1)^(-1)*exp(acos(zeta(1))/tan(acos(zeta(1))))" , then divide it by 10.

Comment: @EOFF Ok, but where did you get that formula from? I have never seen it before.

Comment: @SampleTime The formula is for calculation of rise time

Comment: Why not just use the bandwidth? `0.1/(max(omega_0)/(2*pi))`

Comment: @SampleTime Thanks! I didn't know I could use that